# PayPal express API call doesn't re-direct response back to my URL

Tags: php, paypal

friends!  Well, when working with Web Payments Standard and PDT, it was explained to me that when a user tries to pay with a credit card and without logging in, the auto forward back to my site does not work... same person recommended PayPal Express as my solution.  So here I am implementing my very first ever API call, and instead of re-directing back to my site to look at the POST or GET response NVP data, I get a long response string on the PayPal API page... I am posting my code below.  Any thoughts?  I have a screen shot, but can't figure out how to post it...

```
<form action="https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp" method="post" name="PPform" id="PPform">
  <input type="hidden" name="USER" value=" user " />
  <input type="hidden" name="PWD" value=" password " />
  <input type="hidden" name="SIGNATURE" value="signature" />
  <input type="hidden" name="VERSION" value="109.0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION" value="Sale" />
  <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="0.30" />
  <input type="hidden" name="RETURNURL" value="https://www.masphotopdx.com/process.php" />
  <input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="https://www.masphotopdx.com/mas_cart.php" />
  <input type="submit" name="METHOD" value="SetExpressCheckout" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does the sandbox (https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp) work?

Comment: Contrary to popular wisdom, I haven't used the sandbox yet... it is easier for me to test a non-paypal credit card (kind of the worst case scenario) by running live with a small charge...  Also, at this point, it costs me nothing to try a basic query exchange since no payment conformation is asked for up front...

Comment: The fact that I get the exact same behavior when I query PayPal PDT (response posted to PayPal's page as a long response string, without re-direct back to my site) suggests that I am doing something fundamentally wrong here, or I have a basic setting incorrect...

Comment: Check the settings in your Paypal profile - you can set a return url there as well.

Comment: It is set there.  Exactly the same as in the code above

Answer (score 0):

The variables are `RETURN_URL` and `CANCEL_URL`. You can also set the URL in your Paypal profile.

Comment: Hmm... let me try adding the underscore... wow, I copy the code from the PayPal documentation... and still it is wrong.  Anyone but me not surprised?

Comment: Nope, that isn't it... adding the underscores caused a score of errors saying that no return or cancel url was supplied.

Comment: TIMESTAMP=2013%2d11%2d06T23%3a30%3a05Z&CORRELATIONID=dc257e2686ebf&ACK=Failure&VERSION=109%2e0&BUILD=8334781&L_ERRORCODE0=10404&L_ERRORCODE1=10405&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Transaction%20refused%20because%20of%20an%20invalid%20argument%2e%20See%20additional%20error%20messages%20for%20details%2e&L_SHORTMESSAGE1=Transaction%20refused%20because%20of%20an%20invalid%20argument%2e%20See%20additional%20error%20messages%20for%20details%2e&L_LONGMESSAGE0=ReturnURL%20is%20missing%2e&L_LONGMESSAGE1=CancelURL%20is%20missing%2e&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error&L_SEVERITYCODE1=Error

Comment: And here it is without the underscore:

Comment: TOKEN=EC%2d7E239404108742022&TIMESTAMP=2013%2d11%2d06T23%3a34%3a45Z&CORRELATIONID=543c71739a275&ACK=Success&VERSION=109%2e0&BUILD=8334781

Comment: But that message is posted as a single string on the otherwise blank page at api-3t.paypal.com/nvp

Comment: It seems clear to me now that the form structure, in spite of PayPal's use of this structure in their examples, is not the proper way to interact with the Express Payment API.

Comment: I checked my own script and I'm passing the URL's as is for the same API call using curl. Where does it return you after completion?